# How to identify if the method call is inside a lambda expression or outside of it in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, locking, mutex

I have two methods, read and write, which locks the mutex, does the required operation and unlocks it.

The other lambda method batch takes any function as the parameter, locks the mutex, activates the batch mode, executes the passed function and deactivates batch mode.

The problem is, when any method, say read/write is passed inside the batch, it will result in a deadlock. How can I identify if the function fn is executing inside batch so as to avoid multiple mutex locking? i.e. if 'fn' is the kind of function that locks the mutex, then it must not lock mutex while executing inside batch, which already has the functionality to lock mutex before 'fn' execution.

Please suggest if there is any workaround for the problem too.

Code example:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Resource
{
    mutable std::mutex mtx;
    int value = 10;

    void batchModeActivate()
    {/* Activate batch mode */
        std::cout << "Batch mode activate!" << std::endl;
    }
    void batchModeDeactivate()
    {/* Activate batch mode */
        std::cout << "Batch mode deactivate!" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    int read() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        return value + 10;
    }
    void write(int val)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        value = val;
    }
    
    template<typename Fn>
    void batch(Fn fn)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        batchModeActivate();
        fn();
        batchModeDeactivate();
    }
    
    void print() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Resource r;
    r.print();
    r.write(r.read());
    r.print();
    
    r.batch([&]
    {
        auto someVal = r.read();
        auto someOtherVal = 10 + someVal;
        r.write(r.read() + someOtherVal);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you just need a recursive mutex?

Comment: No, I want to avoid multiple locking. I don't want 'fn' to lock mutex if executing inside batch.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure that you are indeed not falling for the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Recursive Mutex sounds fine to me unless you have other reasons.

Comment: a recursive mutex is what prevents from locking more than once. If you call `lock` on an already locked recursive mutex in the same thread nothing really happens. Can you clarify why you dont want to use a recursive mutex? For more information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex

Comment: Have the `Fn` take a `bool` that indicates whether or not it is being executed in the context of a `batch`.